# What does ppc64le mean?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, netboot, ppc

What does ppc64le mean ?

Is it related to Ubuntu only?

Why does it affect netbooting and what should I do to enable netbooting with ppc64le?

Please someone explain this to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

ppc64le is a CPU architecture, specifically the little-endian version of ppc64. Compare this with amd64, another architecture (currently the most common for desktop PCs). It applies to all code that runs on those CPUs and is not Ubuntu-specific. It affects netbooting because machines need to boot a kernel compatible with their CPU.

Comment: So how can I make it work? The netbooting?

Comment: It's just like a normal netboot except for choosing the different architecture's boot image.

Comment: We netboot ppc64le machines at work - as @JosephSible said, you just need that architecture's boot image. Then it depends on whether you're using PowerVM or not - if you're running 'bare metal' without powervm, then you should see the netboot options in Petitboot. I'm not sure what the process is for PowerVM but it should be documented somewhere.